.NET 8.0 console application with ShowWindow(ThisConsole, MAXIMIZE)
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    const int SW_RESTORE = 9;   // Restore window if minimized or not in normal state
    const int SW_MAXIMIZE = 3;  // Command to maximize the window

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsoleManipulator consoleManipulator = new ConsoleManipulator();

            // Bring the console window to the front
            consoleManipulator.BringConsoleToFront();

            // Maximize the console window
            consoleManipulator.MaximizeConsole();

            Console.ReadLine(); // Keep the console open to observe changes
        }
    }

    // Method to bring the console window to the front
    public void BringConsoleToFront()
    {
        IntPtr consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
        if (consoleWindow != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // First, restore the window if it’s minimized or not normal
            ShowWindow(consoleWindow, SW_RESTORE);
            Console.WriteLine("Console restored.");

            // Bring to front
            SetForegroundWindow(consoleWindow);
            Console.WriteLine("Console brought to the front.");
        }
    }

    // Method to maximize the console window
    public void MaximizeConsole()
    {
        IntPtr consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();

        if (consoleWindow != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            ShowWindow(consoleWindow, SW_MAXIMIZE);  // Maximize the window
            Console.WriteLine("Console maximized.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to get console window handle.");
        }
    }

I just create the console application that with extern SetForegroundWindow, ShowWindow and GetConsoleWindow.
When I run the program with the code shown, the consoleManipulator.BringConsoleToFront() brings the console to the front of my Visual Studio, but MaximizeConsole() cannot maximize the console. The console application remain unchanged with actual size height and width...

Try using my NuGet package ConsoleHelperLibrary which targets NET6 and higher.
The following maximizes the console window.
WindowUtility.SetConsoleWindowPosition(WindowUtility.AnchorWindow.Fill);

There are several code samples in the following GitHub repository.

Karen Payne, I try to use the following code in my scripts but doesn't ...maximizes... the console?

I've never had this fail. Try in a new project code that matches this project which sets to full screen at start of the app.

But confirm that fails on net8.0...

Here is a NET8 version project which I just ran and works. And the class project still targets NET5.

Hi Karen, it is running smoothly on my window 11, but the console open at the terminal didn't make the console full-screen using your project as a reference, What window Karen using??

You can check out the video link
https://jmp.sh/Ej5UiSBc
